# How do I put the agent config on a single line?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

This is my agent config:

```
stage('mystage') {
    agent {
        node {
            customWorkspace 'buildfolder'
            label 'abc123'
        }
    }
```

I want to get this on one line but I'm fighting with Groovy syntax. This doesn't work: `agent {node {label:'abc123', customWorkspace:'buildfolder'}}`

```
unexpected token: abc123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all commands should be separated by `;` if they are in one line

```
agent { node { customWorkspace 'buildfolder'; label 'abc123'; } }
```

Comment: is this syntax jenkins specific or is this a groovy thing?

Comment: it's a standard groovy (even java). all commands in java separated with `;`. for groovy it's optional to end each command with `;`. however if you put several commands into one line - you must separate them with semicolon.

Comment: so the node closure is being passed two "commands" ? what are commands?

Comment: i mean this `customWorkspace 'buildfolder'`. i quite sure event this will work: `customWorkspace( 'buildfolder' )` - if yes then it's a function/method..